# how to get a text from an user of google assistant, and response something from a sqlite db

Tags: node.js, sqlite, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, node-red

I want to make a 'question & answer' module using an express server and a sqlite db based on my vps webhook.

What is the correct way?

Thanks

---

so far i've setup (without success) something like:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/antonyharfield/66f3a403b0fbd7fd490fc615d190dc0c/raw/a0c104da569a60f12de9fac02735f75f962caf39/simpleServer.js to start my server and get a welcome message from the google test console, and get the mic open for the query, but I can't get more... (i'm stucked on the first post query to my server). I search a minimal of working code example.

---

Using node-red webhook relay I've got the query and the answer from the db but I cannot send it back to the assistant and I've no Idea how to do it...

---

I've tried also entities first in dialogflow.

Fast & Simple, (no code) but I do not like it.

In https://console.dialogflow.com , do https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/create-manage-entities

I've now two columns where the first is the result and the second the matched query, then playing around in intents i've something like this [dialogflow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hKQ9.png) [n.b.: 'numeroptl' is the name of the entity value.]

It works but catch only the first result.

---

Trying to make it a very simple question, in my csv:

"first street", "left side", "carlo"

"first street", "right side", "giovanna"

"second street", "all", "mario"

how can i tell to google assistant as example:

- "first street"

and have in response:

- "carlo (left side), giovanna (right side)"

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code from the "entities system", but it sounds like this is along the lines of what you need to do. If you're getting multiple responses from your database, you will need to either merge the responses in some way, or determine how to let the user know there is additional information that they can get, and how to get it.

Comment: I can't figure that

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the csv example, map the left column to [entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-overview). For example, in this case first street and second street can be recognized as @sys.location entities.

[image: Training phrases]

[image: Action and parameters]

If you enable the [webhook fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how), the parameters you define will be sent to your server on the intent detect.

[image: Example of JSON response]

You can use these parameters to do a sql query and get the results you want. Finally send the response as text, or, since you are using Google Assistant, as a [RichResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages#top_of_page).

```js
//Using dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
function other(agent) {

    // Parameters are located in agent.parameters
    let locationInput = agent.parameters.location

    // Your db code here

    // Response using suggestions
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Carlo (left side)`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Giovanna (right side)`));
  }
```

[image: Suggestion response example]

You can find a tutorial to Dialogflow [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/), and dialogflow-fulfillment samples [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs#samples).

Now, you don't have to use a library for the fulfillment, just follow the API [requests](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-request-body) and [response](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-response-body) formats.